# How to post MAF form data to Rest service in Json format?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

I have created a `REST` service which is working fine with `GET` method.

I want to post form data in `JSON` format with `POST` method. I have a ready form in `MAF` and a `REST` service which is working with `GET`.

How can I connect both using `REST/JSON` Service.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your inputted data to your `POJO` object (the same you use to perform your `GET`) and then convert the `POJO` back to JSON and perform a `POST`.

**An example can be found here:** [Please click this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_json/tut_jdev_maf_json_2.html).